# How i can deploying RESTful Api Flask on windows server

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="137.159.x.x")
```

I tried to put my IP on `app.run(host="137.159.x.x")`
but it's not working and where should I put file project on windows server

please help me, thank you.

Comment: I think Flask is for development purposes, not for production. So, if you want to run it on a server, then you need to use another method. I, myself, use uWSGI server. check [this link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/uwsgi/)

Comment: Thank you, but i have already a windows server

Comment: You should check what @Anwarvic suggested, it should work with your windows server.